# How and when does Magento load the base configuration, the module configuration, and the database configuration?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

I am get confused a little bit about the correct answer for this question, may be it is small.

**One**  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php

```
 public function run($params)
{
    $this->baseInit($options);
    $this->_initModules();
    $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

        if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
            $scopeCode = isset($params['scope_code']) ? $params['scope_code'] : '';
            $scopeType = isset($params['scope_type']) ? $params['scope_type'] : 'store';
            $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
            $this->_initRequest();
            Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
        }

        $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Base configuration as well as Module configuration is loading by below code when request something.

```
$this->_config->loadBase();
$this->_config->loadModules();
$this->_config->loadDb();
```

**Two** app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php

```
public function init($code, $type = null, $options = array())
{

    $this->_initEnvironment();
    $this->_config = Mage::getConfig();
    $this->_config->setOptions($options);
    $this->_initBaseConfig();
    $this->_initCache();
    $this->_config->init($options);

    if (Mage::isInstalled($options)) {
        $this->_initCurrentStore($code, $type);
        $this->_initRequest();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

It is calling when we call Stactic Method  **Mage::app();** initializing configuration and loading

Based on **One and Two** Config loading which is the correct answer for tagged (How and when does Magento load .... ) question ?

Any answer appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento have three executing function (Mage::init(), Mage::app(), Mage::run()). But there are two main functions that usually use for executing, that is Mage::app(), Mage::run().

You can read this: http://vncosy.com/magento-what-is-the-difference-regarding-module-loading-between-magerun-and-mageapp/

Comment: cool answer , But what if get asked above question ( how and when does ... base configuration, the module configuration, and the database configuration? ) .  Do I have to say Mage::app() or by the public function run().